# React GSAP Animation - Not able to animate rows

Tags: reactjs, gsap

i have a table component that is wrapped inside a Transition group. When i am animating the table row than some how the table border appears as soon as the page appears and table cells with data appears later. I want the rows and data should animate together at the same time.

```
import React from "react";
    import GSAP from 'react-gsap-enhancer';
    import 'gsap';
    import TransitionGroup from 'react-addons-transition-group';
    import TableRow from './TableRow'


    function componentAppearOrEnter(){
        console.log("Table Component Will Appear");
        const tableRef = document.getElementById("tableRef");
        TweenMax.from(tableRef, 0.3, {opacity: 0, scale : 0,    ease:Expo.easeOut});
        var table = document.getElementById("tableRef");
        var tl = new TimelineMax({delay:0.1, repeat:0, repeatDelay:1})
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           tl.add( TweenLite.to(row, 0, {opacity:0}) );
           tl.add(TweenLite.to(row,.1,{x:0,y:2,opacity:1, clearProps: "all"}));
        }
    }
    class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }
    componentWillAppear(callback) {
        componentAppearOrEnter();
        callback();
    }
    componentWillEnter(callback) {
        console.log("Table Component Will Appear");
        const tableRef = document.getElementById("tableRef");
        TweenMax.from(tableRef, 0.3, {opacity: 0, scale : 0, ease:Expo.easeOut,delay:.3});
        var table = document.getElementById("tableRef");
        var tl = new TimelineMax({delay:0.1, repeat:0, repeatDelay:1})
        for (var i = 0,row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           tl.add( TweenLite.to(row, 0, {opacity:0}) );
           tl.add(TweenLite.to(row,.1,{x:0,y:2,opacity:1, clearProps: "all"}));
        }
        callback();
    }


    /*componentWillEnter(callback){
        console.log(" Table Entered");
        callback();
    }*/
    componentWillLeave(callback) {
        console.log("Table Component Will Leave");
        var table = document.getElementById("tableRef");
        TweenMax.fromTo(table, .3, {x: 0, opacity: 1}, {x: -1000, opacity: 0,   onComplete: callback});

    }

    render(){

        return(
        <div>

            <table id="tableRef" className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick} > 
                        <td>Video1.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust1</td>
                        <td> v1.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video2.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust2</td>
                        <td> v2.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video1.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust3</td>
                        <td> v1.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video2.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust4</td>
                        <td> v2.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video1.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust4</td>
                        <td> v1.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video2.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust5</td>
                        <td> v2.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video1.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust6</td>
                        <td> v1.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr onClick={this.props.rowClick}> 
                        <td>Video2.avi</td>
                        <td>Cust7</td>
                        <td> v2.0</td>
                        <td>01-01-2016</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
        );



    }
}
export default GSAP()(Table)
```

Comment: posible to create a jsfiddle or something please?